# Windowing functions cumulative aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum, windowing

I am calculating cumulative by summing some columns. The code is working. But I want to include an extra variable for the first line only. Then it miscalculates.

What I want to do in line 1:

```
SUM(@devir + netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem)
```

What I want to do except line 1:

```
SUM(netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem)
```

When I do this with case, the wrong result is obtained.

SQL code:

```
declare @devir float = 1308973;
    WITH asilTablo AS(
        select * from #tmpbrut1
        union
        select * from #tmpbrut
    )
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by takasTarihi) >= 2 then
        SUM(netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem) OVER (ORDER BY takasTarihi ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        else SUM(@devir + netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem)  OVER (ORDER BY takasTarihi ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) end AS [Kümülatif Toplam]
    FROM asilTablo
```

So for example on line 1, it will do this:

```
@devir+netTakas-ToplamCikis+YeniKredKullanımı-Islem = Kümülatif Toplam
```

In places other than line 1, it will do this:

```
Kümülatif Toplam + netTakas-ToplamCikis+YeniKredKullanımı-Islem
```

[image]

`@devir = 10` operation on the first line:

```
@devir + netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem
```

[image]

Operations on the other line:

```
netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem
```

Operations of variables and columns in the first row, The sum of the columns in the row 1 and the column in the "cumulative total" in the next row

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp1(
     tarih date,
    netTakas int,
    ToplamCikis int,
    YeniKrediKullanımı int,
    Islem int
)

CREATE TABLE #Tmp2(
     tarih date,
    netTakas int,
    ToplamCikis int,
    YeniKrediKullanımı int,
    Islem int
)

insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211227', 125, 34, 57, 347)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211228', 135, 34, 587, 3624)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211229', 125, 347, 577, 34)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211230', 175, 344, 597, 374)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211231', 1875, 364, 587, 38684)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20220103', 1295, 354, 575, 344)
insert into #Tmp1 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20220104', 1285, 344, 547, 344)

insert into #Tmp2 (tarih, netTakas, ToplamCikis, YeniKrediKullanımı, Islem) VALUES ('20211226', 12453485, 3444, 5447, 34544)

declare @devir float = 1308973;
WITH asilTablo AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #Tmp1
union
Select *
from #Tmp2
)
SELECT  
    tarih,
    netTakas,
    ToplamCikis,
    YeniKrediKullanımı,
    Islem,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by tarih) >= 2 then SUM(netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem) OVER (ORDER BY tarih ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
    else  SUM(@devir + netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem) OVER (ORDER BY tarih ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  end  AS [Kümülatif Toplam]
FROM
    asilTablo
```

Comment: please enter sample data and desired output

Comment: I don't know how else to explain. quite clear.  in the first line  netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem I'm throwing the result of the operation into a column called "kümülatif toplam". In lines other than line 1 In the other rows, I take the value in the "kümülatif toplam" column of the top row and perform mathematical operations and put it back in the "kümülatif toplam" column. @MeysamAsadi

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but I need the data in the "cumulative total" column in the next row. How can I get it to start the process from line 2?

Comment: Please enter the data of the tables as text and not the image and then enter the output you want from the table as a table to get a quick answer

Comment: bro...     When calculating the first row, the variable will be included, while the other rows will not include the variable. it's that simple. this is my aim. I updated the question.  I probably need to update the "between unbounded preceding" part but I don't know what to write

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No it isn't, it's `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` which is subtly different, slower and can cause incorrect results in many cases. Although the current syntax can be shortened to `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`

Comment: Comment deleted, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ROW_NUMBER()` on inner query. On outer query check for when `ROW_NUMBER()`  = `1` include `@devir` in calculation

```
SELECT
    SUM (CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN @devir ELSE 0 END
         + netTakas - ToplamCikis + YeniKrediKullanımı - Islem) 
    OVER (ORDER BY tarih)
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by tarih ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM   asilTablo
) a
```

Comment: omg. Finally someone who understands me. thank you king.

Comment: You're missing `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, it's faster as well as giving correct results in case of tied ordering

Comment: edited to `order by tarih ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`

Comment: @Squirrel Quick question, what's the role of the `=` in the inner query? ('RN = ROW_NUMER` etc. Thanks

Comment: @PeterSmith It's equivalent to `ROW_NUMBER() ... AS RN` it's a way of doing a column alias. See https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases